# Django: model index is just too slow

Tags: python, database, django

I am recently building a database for chemical compounds with Django. I have a trouble dealing with the model traverse. The following is my problem:

Models:

```
class CompoundStructures(models.Model):
    molregno           = models.CharField(max_length=27L, primary_key=True)
    molfile            = models.TextField(blank=True)
    standard_inchi     = models.TextField(blank=True)
    standard_inchi_key = models.CharField(max_length=27L, unique=True)
    canonical_smiles   = models.TextField(blank=True)
    molformula         = models.CharField(max_length=100L, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'compound_structures'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.molformula
```

There are 1,000,000+ records in the database for this model:
I run code like this:

```
all_mols = CompoundStructures.objects.all()

mol_0 = all_mols[0]                 //quick
mol_100 = all_mols[100]            //normal
mol_10000 = all_mols[10000]       //slow 
mol_100000 = all_mols[100000]    //really slow!
```

Why is it become much more slower as the index number become bigger?
This makes it impossible for me to traverse the `CompoundStructures`.

Comment: Why are you trying to traverse a database model as if it's a giant array? 

You should look up the records based on a key. It might help if you explained why you want the 10,000th record, maybe someone could recommend and alternate way to do this.

Comment: If you added the records in order and your primary keys are in order, can you use `all_mols.get(id=10000)`, `all_mols.get(id=100000)`, etc?

Comment: If I use sentence like "all_mols.get(id=10000)", then it shall connect the database each time I retrive one mol. This might be costly.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing

```
mol_100000 = all_mols[100000]
```

Django evaluates the QuerySet from `CompoundStructures.objects.all()`

This will always be slow since you fetched all of the mols and now want the 100000th mol, it's only logical.

If you want to fetch one (1) mol from the entire millions of rows then `.get(id=100000)` is your only option when using the database and Django's ORM.

Using the `.get()` here isn't more costly than what you're trying to do now, ie. fetch all and then evaluate the QuerySet.

Comment: I actually need to traverse through all the objects.

Comment: Okay, so do that with the normal `for`.